# Squid logs show "TCP_DENIED/407" error

Tags: internet, proxy, squid

I'm using Squid 3.0

**Example:** I want to download software from cnet. After launching CNET Download.com Installer, I get an error:

> Internet connection error
>
> We're unable to connect to the download server. It seems that your internet connection is down or firewalled. Please check your internet and proxy setting then click the "Try Again" button below.

I checked Squid, and got the error:

```
1319791754.173      1 192.168.1.101 TCP_DENIED/407 2081 GET http://api.cnet.com/rest/v1.0/softwareProductLink? - NONE/- text/html
1319791754.396      1 192.168.1.101 TCP_DENIED/407 2194 GET http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd - NONE/- text/html
```

I searched for "TCP_DENIED/407" but I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The 407 error is coming from squid, telling the calling application that it must provide authentication credential to continue.

With a browser, this is straightforward, it would pop-up asking for the credentials if it didn't already have them, and the user would type them in.

For non-interactive applications like a downloader, they should have a mechanism for entering the credentials into their configuration.

Comment: Thanks alot Paul for quick reply. I agreed with you but I think should be a solution for that.Second when I try to use Adobe Download Assistant is asking me for the credentials but squid logs says the same issue (TCP_DENIED/407) so in the two cases I can not download over squid proxy! Do you think is there a solution for that? Thanks again.

Comment: The 407 should always happen when the initial connection starts - then the credentials are provided, and the request happens again.  This is the one you are looking for - check the squid logs to see if the credentials weren't accepted for some reason.

Comment: can't find any thing interesting in logs, I still have the same problem